# Is it possible to manually freeze a page from an addon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've seen this question [Page Lifecycle API - Is it possible to manually freeze a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67811924/page-lifecycle-api-is-it-possible-to-manually-freeze-a-page)

It hasn't answered of how to freeze a tab **by code** - **from an addon**. It describes how to do it manually by **mouse**.

How to do it? Has it become possible in the latest versions of Chrome?